# Dynamic HTTP request routing using rules implemented in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, routes, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I would like to use a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function to implement dynamic routing rules for HTTP requests targeted at a fleet of [Fargates](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). I need the Lambda function because routing rules require dynamic lookups to be made on an external database service (Redis cluster in this case).

Is there a way to do that using [Elastic Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) or [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)?

Is thee any other option that I should consider?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a Lambda function be part of the routing logic of either of those services. This would have to be something that you created yourself.

Each of the Lambda functions would have to know about the endpoints of the targets and when to send traffic there.

Comment: What would be the best serverless way to create such a custom router? I need the requester to connect directly with the target Fargate.